# Oracle : processing table records concurrently and updating in Java

Tags: java, oracle, multithreading

I have table `tele_detais` which contains millions (~10 million) of records. Table has below columns majorly :

```
TN: varchar2 (unique 10 digit number PK),
xyz :varchar2,
abc :varchar2 , 
mailids :varchar2, 
status :number , 
emailstatus :number
```

I have to process all the records in 10 hrs. So logic would be to get each record or set of records  (there wont be any where clause in query as we have to process all the available records ), do some business logic [call some update and get param value for TN] and sent email to mention email id's in column and update email status.

As I have to process all the records in specific time, so there will be multiple threads and accessing the table and get the records and then process it.

Issues :

1. As there is no where clause in the query because we need to process all the available records so how to select records from table as there will be multiple thread selecting at the same time so need to ensure each thread process different record ?
2. As there will be multiple thread selecting records at the same time so some locking must be required to ensure 2 thread shouldnt get same record.
3. what will be select query ? may be limit need to maintain while selecting records....

I need help to understand this and how it can be done.

I searched on google but couldn't get how to handle if multiple thread accessing records without where clause in query then how to ensure each thread getting different record and then need to update it as well later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have one single thread reading the database table that feeds the rows one by one into pooled worker threads. No locking required because there is only one thread per row working on it.